# Mouseover not working on repeated hovering

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Online Grocery Store </title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style >
        .maincoloumn {
            float : left;
            width : 48%;
            height :100%;
            border:1px solid black;


        }
        #second{

            float: right;
            width: 50%;
            height: 50%;
            border:1px solid black;

            top: 0;
        }
        #third{
            position:absolute;
            margin-top:20%;
            margin-right:50%;
        }
        #tableStuff{
            float:right;
        }





        .header
         {

            padding: 20px;
            text-align: left
         }



    th {

                    width: 10%;
                    padding-top: 12px;
                    padding-bottom: 12px;
                    text-align: left;
                    background-color: #4CAF50;
                    color: white;


                }
    #displayDescriptions{

        margin-top:15%;
        margin-left:20%;
        margin-right:5%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: none;
        width: 40%;

    }

    th:hover {background-color: #006400;}

    #tableContents th{

         padding-top: 12px;
         padding-bottom: 12px;
         text-align: center;
         background-color: blue;
         color: yellow;



    }

    #seaFoodContents{

        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;


        color: black;
        font-style: bold;
        width: 80%;
    }
    #listFrozenProducts li:hover{
        background-color: #006400;
    }


    #listFrozenProducts{
        display:none;
    }
    #listFrozenSeaProducts{
        display:none;
    }
    #listMilkProducts{
        display:none;
    }





    #listFrozenProducts ul{
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        width:50%;
        text-align: left;
        text-decoration: bold;
        height:40%;

        border-radius: 25px;


    }

    #listFrozenProducts ul li {
        display: inline;
        padding: 20px 20px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border-color: #006400;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: bold;


    }


    div.seaFoodList {

      width:30%;
      display: inline-block;

      background-color: white;
      border:black;


    }


    div.container1 {

      text-align: left;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
        div.gallery {
            margin: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
        }

        div.gallery:hover {
            border: 1px solid #777;
        }

        div.gallery img {
            position: relative;

            width:  100%;
            height: 200px;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            background-repeat:   no-repeat;
            background-size:     cover
        }

        div.desc {
            padding: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #displayDescriptions{
            display:block;
        }


    div.productList
    {
            font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

            text-decoration: bold;

            list-style-type: none;

            margin-left:0;

            padding-left:30px;

            text-indent: -4px;

            list-style-type:none;




    }
    div.productList li{
     font-size:20px;

     list-style-type: none;
     background-color: #4CAF50;
     color: white;




    }
    #NestedClasses {
        background-color:
        font-size:1px;
        margin-left:10%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color:#006400;
        width:40%;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        border-radius: 25px;




    }
    div.productList li:hover{
        background-color: #006400;
    }
    #NestedClasses a { color: inherit; } 

    div.productList a{color:white;}

    #listOtherProducts{
        display:none;
    }
    #freshProducts{
        display:none;
 }
 #listMeatProducts{
    display:none;
 }


</style>



<script>

function frozenFoodDisplay() {
    document.getElementById("listFrozenProducts").style.display= "block";
    removeFreshFood();




}
function seaFoodGone() {

    document.getElementById("listFrozenSeaProducts").style.display= "none";
    removeFreshFood();

}
function seaFoodDisplay()
{
        frozenFoodDisplay();
        milkProductsGone();
        otherProductsGone();
        removeFreshFood();
        document.getElementById('listFrozenSeaProducts').style.display="block";
}
function otherProductsDisplay(){
        document.getElementById("listOtherProducts").style.display="block";
        removeFreshFood();
        seaFoodGone();
        milkProductsGone();
}

function milkProductsDisplay(){
    document.getElementById("listMilkProducts").style.display="block";
    removeFreshFood();
    seaFoodProductsGone();
    otherProductsGone();


}
function ProductsGone(){
    document.getElementById("listFrozenProducts").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("listFrozenSeaProducts").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("listMilkProducts").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("listOtherProducts").style.display="none";
}
function milkProductsGone(){
;
    document.getElementById("listMilkProducts").style.display="none";

}
function seaFoodProductsGone(){
    document.getElementById("listFrozenSeaProducts").style.display="none";

}
function otherProductsGone(){
    document.getElementById("listFrozenSeaProducts").style.display="none";

}
function frozenFoodGone(){
    document.getElementById('getRidOfFrozenFood').style.display="none";
}
function freshFoodDisplay(){
    document.getElementById('freshProducts').style.display="block";
    frozenFoodGone();


}

function displayMeatProducts(){
    freshFoodDisplay();
    document.getElementById('listMeatProducts').style.display="block";
}
function meatProductsGone()
{
    frozenFoodGone();
    document.getElementById('listMeatProducts').style.display="none";

}
function removeFreshFood(){
    document.getElementById('getRidOfFreshFood').style.display="none";
}

function listFrozenFood(){
    removeFreshFood();
    document.getElementById('listFrozenProducts').style.display="block";
}


</script>

</head>

<body>



<div class="maincoloumn"  onmouseleave="ProductsGone()" >
        <h1 class="header">Grocery store</h1>


                <table>

                        <tr>
                             <th width="(95/x)%" onmouseover="frozenFoodDisplay()">Frozen Food</th>
                             <th width="(95/x)%" onmouseover="freshFoodDisplay()">Fresh Food </th>
                             <th width="(95/x)%">Beverages</th>
                             <th width="(95/x)%">Home health</th>
                             <th width="(95/x)%">Pet food</th>
                        </tr>



                </table>
                <br>
    <div id="getRidOfFrozenFood" onmouseLeave="frozenFoodGone()">   
                <div id="listFrozenProducts" onmouseover="listFrozenFood()">
                    <ul>
                        <li onmouseover="seaFoodDisplay()">Sea Food </li>
                        <li onmouseover="milkProductsDisplay()">Milk Products</li>
                        <li onmouseover="otherProductsDisplay()">Others</li>
                    </ul>                           

                </div>    
                <br>
            <div id="listFrozenSeaProducts"  onmouseleave="seaFoodProductsGone()">

                <div class="productList">
                    <ul>

                         <li style="border-style: solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#006400;width:40%;padding-left:20px">Fish Fingers </li>


                           <br>
                           <div id="NestedClasses">
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1000">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1000').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1000" name="name"> Fish Fingers(Small)</li>
                            </form>
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1001">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1001').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1001" name="name"> Fish Fingers (Large)</li>
                            </form>

                           </div>   

                     </ul>
                    <ul>
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1003">
                <li style="border-style: solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#006400;width:40%;padding-left:20px"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1003').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1003" name="name"> Shelled Prawns</a></li>
                            </form>
                    </ul>
                   </div>  
                 </div>





                <div id="listMilkProducts" onmouseleave="milkProductsGone()">
                         <div class="productList">
                    <ul>

                         <li style="border-style: solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#006400;width:40%;padding-left:20px">Tube Ice Cream </li>


                           <br>
                           <div id="NestedClasses">
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1004">
                                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1000').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1004" name="name"> Tube Ice Cream -1 litre</a></li>
                            </form>
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1005">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1001').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1005" name="name"> Tube Ice Cream-2 litre</a></li>
                            </form>

                           </div>   

                    </ul>
                    </div>
                  </div>  
                <div id="listOtherProducts" onmouseleave="otherProductsGone()">
                        <div class="productList">
                        <ul>
                        <form action="index.php" method="post" id="1002">
            <li style="border-style: solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#006400;width:40%;padding-left:20px"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('1002').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="1002" name="name"> Hamburger Patties</a></li>
                         </form>
                        </ul>

                        </div>  
                 </div>




    </div>

    <div id="getRidOfFreshFood" onmouseleave="freshFoodGone()">
        <div id="freshProducts" onmouseover="freshFoodDisplay()">
            <ul>
                        <li onmouseover="displayMeatProducts()">Meat </li>
                        <li onmouseover="">Cheese</li>
                        <li onmouseover="">Fruits</li>
            </ul>       
        </div>
        <div id="listMeatProducts" onmouseleave="meatProductsGone()">
                <div class="productList">
                        <ul>
                        <form action="index.php" method="post" id="3002">
            <li style="border-style: solid;border-radius:25px;border-color:#006400;width:40%;padding-left:20px"><a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('3002').submit();"><input type="hidden" value="3002" name="name"> T'Bone Steak</a></li>
                         </form>
                        </ul>

                </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

There is no error now on JSFIDDLE as well as mozilla developer. Any thing wrong with the function call? Could anyone give any suggestions on how to atleast work around it or any reasons this is failing? I am thinking of using hover? Or any other way I can get it to display? Many thanks again for spending your valued time on this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You have problems with `grammar`. Like `<div class="maincoloumn"  "onmouseleave="ProductsGone()" >`. Is right as `<div class="maincoloumn"  onmouseleave="ProductsGone()" >`.

Comment: Please post the important part of the code.

Comment: @informant09 could you kindly tell me which part?

Comment: @AjAX. still that doesnot fix the issue.Thank you

Comment: @ZenStan No sorry I wont do the work for you. Provide the important part of the code and more people are willing to help you.

Comment: No, there are plenty. Check in https://jsfiddle.net. Or use an `IDE` with `syntax highlighting`.

Comment: @AjAX. I have corrected it, but still no issues fixed

Comment: Can you post the `code` with the issues fixed.

Comment: @AjAX. if you kindly copy paste it on a text editor, you can see what I am referring to.

Comment: You trigger the `display:none` on `parent` elements. Of the `elements` with `display:block`. That does — not — work.

Comment: @AjAX. any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: You want to sanely restructure. Think about it. %)P